# Can I change case of property Id to support CosmosDB need for it to be id

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

I am getting messages from Salesforce and the message payload has a property called Id, however CosmoDB is failed with the message "required properties - 'id' is missing". Looks like it wants the property to be in lowercase.

I believe in code I would use something like below.  However in the logic app I do not know what the equivalent would be.

[JsonProperty("id")]
public string Id { get; init; }

[image]

Comment: how are you doing it in logic app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a variable called Message and then used replace function.

```
replace(variables('Message'),'"Id":','"id":')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Initially I have created logic app as shown below.
   [image]
2. When I run logic app flow, it is failing at cosmos db action with the below error

`Message: {\"Errors\":[\"The input content is invalid because the required properties - 'id; ' - are missing.`

[image]

3. The error can be seen in below screen shot.
   [image]
4. I have modified logic app as shown below.
   [image]
5. In compose action I have formed a Json and assigned **id** value from salesforce payload unique value.
   [image]
6. In create or update document action, given **outputs(‘Compose’)** in Document field.

[image]

7. Logic app ran successfully and inserted in cosmos db.

[image]